# URI is not mapped with Controller in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a REST API using Spring. The code gets compiled without any error. But when I hit the URI using POSTMAN I do not get any result. I checked and found that the controller is not mapping the request to the given URI. Here is my code:

**APIController.java**

```
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

 import java.text.ParseException;


  @RestController
  public class APIController {

  APIService apiservice = new APIService();

   @RequestMapping(value="/getPerson/{id}",method =    RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
  public Person getPerson(@PathVariable @RequestBody int id) throws     ParseException {
    System.out.println("Inside get method");
    Person person=apiservice.getPersonInfo(id);
    return person;

 }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>edu.cmpe275.lab2</groupId>
<artifactId>CMPE275Lab2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CMPE275Lab2</name>
<description>CMPE275Lab2 project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<start-class>CMPE275Lab2.CMPE275Lab2Application</start-class>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- twilio sms api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Mongodb driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Bean Copyutils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons- beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3_2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Joda time if java <= 1.7, not needed for java 1.8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- servlet container provided dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.30</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- test dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
    <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

URI Mapping is in the APIController class, which is not being called. 
Please advice.

Comment: Can you also post the spring config xml and web xml?

Comment: public Person getPerson(@PathVariable @RequestBody int id)

Comment: I guess you need only @PathVariable here.

Comment: Agree with @Haim ATRequestBody is not necessary if you are not passing the id as part of the request body . Try removing it and see. check the console for any errors.